# How do I get IDLE to find NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk, python-idle

Programming noob here. I'm on Mac OS 10.5.8. I have Python 2.7.6 and have installed NLTK. If I run Python from Terminal, I can "import nltk" with no problem. But if I open IDLE (either from Terminal or by double-clicking on the application) and try the same thing there, I get an error message, "ImportError: No module named nltk". I assume this is a path problem, but what exactly should I do?

The directory where I installed NLTK is "My Documents/Python/nltk-2.0.4". But within this there are  various other directories called  build, dist, etc. Which of these is the exact directory that IDLE needs to be able to find? And how do I add that directory to IDLE's path?

Answer (score 1):

Supplementing the answer above, when you install python packages they will install under the default version of python you are using. Since the module imports in python 2.7.6 make sure that you aren't using the Python 3 version of IDLE.

Comment: Thanks - I'm in IDLE 2.7.6.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the link given below:

[setting-up-nltk-with-python-idle-on-os-x-10-6](http://letraitementsuperbe.wordpress.com/2011/03/06/setting-up-nltk-with-python-idle-on-os-x-10-6/)

HTH! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks - tried that, but now I get a different string of error messages - too long to post here, but it ends like this:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/pl196x.py", line 11, in <module>
    from nltk import tokenize, tree
ImportError: cannot import name tokenize
Any ideas?

Comment: I reinstalled NLTK in the Python 2.7 site-packages folder, and it's working now! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Great! Now try running `nltk.download()` and install packages and models. Happy Hacking..!